# Cassandra date model - redoing secondary index based on date

Tags: cassandra, microservices, primary-key, partitioning

Have a spring boot Microservices that runs as a batch job .. it fires query based on previous day date ( a secondary index ) which is quite inefficient . What are the strategies to create a more efficient query ? We thought of creating a 2 column lookup table with the date as primary key ( and the primary key of the original key as another column ). So we would have 2 primary key queries  . But this wouldnt work as the date field in Cassandra is not unique and can’t be used as primary key . ( ( btw, date is passed from Java up to hundredth of a second ) . Since the Java batch job and query is driven at a specific time ( no other input data ) is available in order to make the data in lookup table unique . Any ideas on how to generate a unique primary key for the lookup table ?

Comment: It will be very useful if you provide your data model - table "create" statement and the query you use to fetch the data.

Comment: Here you request on a table, not with the primary key so may have tried to ALLOW FILTERING, then secondary index, then maybe Materialized views. But you cannot escape the rule. 1 table = 1 query.  So create a new table with the same data for this job request. For the column used a TIMEUUID (100s precision)

Comment: return_item {  account text ,

Comment: return_item {  account text , txn_id , return_date  date(currently secondary index ) , vendor_no text , refund_amount double  , adjustment_file_date date , vendor_rtntxnIddte text (partitioning key ) }       ( its an ecommerce application that processes payments ( sales and refunds )    . The queries fired are an insert based on partitioning key and a  select query based on return_date which has bad performance.  So thought of making a lookup table with the return_date( can make it unique by inserting as a time stamp ) as paritioing key and then the  vendor_rtntxnIddte as another column

Comment: so a 2 query lookup would be used. But since we fire the seondary index query at a specific time  based on previous days date( year , month and day ) ( and we dont have any other column data to drive the query . What should the new data model be  ? or is there a way to design the lookup table a combination of elements that could be unique ? ( looking for inputs on how to model this this specific day driven scenario  )

Comment: What version of Cassandra is this? Plus all the details like full table schema, queries, sample rows, etc., asked by other folks will help to triage this effectively.